# how to extecute multiple select queries with different returning data in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, function

I'm using postgreql and i have two tables and i want to execute two select queries on them. the data that returning from each select are varying! 
the data that returns from first table is:

```
id integer, first_name varchar, last_name varchar, email varchar, company varchar,positions varchar,address varchar,phone varchar
```

and the second table return:

```
group_contact_id integer, contact_id integer, group_id integer
```

i want to do it in a function like this:

```
create function findcontactbyid(id integer) returns table (id integer, first_name varchar, last_name varchar, email varchar, company varchar,positions varchar,address varchar,phone varchar, group_contact_id integer, contact_id integer, group_id integer) as $$
select * from cms_contact where id = $1
UNION ALL
select * from cms_groups_contacts where contact_id = $1
$$ language 'sql'
```

but i get errors
$1 mentions to (id integer) and it exists in both tables

Answer (score 0):

I rather wonder about your function! What do you really need here.

Comeback to the issues:
I think it will raise an error because PostgreSQL have an ambiguous between id (INPUT), id (RETURN) and id of tables in query. So, if you can, you can named it different to each other and then check it again.

The second think, I have some worry about the UNION QUERY. In my knowledge, when you want to UNION 2 query to each other, the result of both query must be the same column and the same type of column.

So, I think after you fix the first issue, the function is also can not run. But you can try first.